# Controlling multiple PIC microcontrollers with a 2-wire setup via GPIOs

Tags: pic

I am working on a small project that consists of a PIC18F4550 acting as a master and other various PIC18F4550 acting as slaves. The distance between the PICs will be more likely about 30 meters (~100Ft). I would like to communicate between the PICs via a 2 wire interface as the image below:

[image]

The blue wire ON RA0 will be sending a clock signal so that the PICs will sync with each other and sending data will be more reliable (at least I think so).

The red wires will be connected to other PICs.

The target is to send an array of bits on the GPIO like :

- Command: PorchControl("BULBS ON")
- This will be converted to binary
- 01000010 01010101 01001100 01000010 01010011 00100000 01001111 01001110
- binary streamed via RA1
- SLAVE 1 will convert binary back to text
- SLAVE 1 will parse the command and switch on the bulbs in the porch
- **SLAVE 1 WILL SEND a confirmation BACK.**

Questions:

-1- Is it possible to do in a much more convenient manner?

-2- Any tips for the programming piece about Txing and Rxing the bits?

Thanks,
J. Wayne

Comment: While this may seem like a reasonable solution, your GPIO will not be able to send a signal 30m very easily. You should look into RS-422 and RS-485 for physical layers that can transmit serial data long distances.

Comment: You have a 30m antenna that efficiently picks up lightning strikes. GPIOs cannot withstand such abuse. Optical transceivers, with 30m of optical fibre have a better chance of surviving.

Comment: The cables will be shielded CAT5 cables to reduce the interference. If I use the RS-422 (using MAX485?) will I be able to control multiple devices on a single output? I have about 15 devices in all... and fiber optic will be very expensive...

Comment: @Wayne Scicluna: Read SLLA070D.pdf from Texas Instruments. Looks like RS-422 is a bit feeble (10 drops max), whereas RS-485 can handle up to 32. I have great respect for lightning - it gets into *anything* electrical!

Comment: @glen_geek this project will be like a test bed for future projects so that I will know everything works as it should be. Then I will use your advice on using optical fibre in a proper installation.

So for now I will try to use the MAX487 for the (RS-485) with the PIC18F4550 :) and if I get struck by lightning... then I hope I will become Flash or something hehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're re-inventing a serial bus.  There is no need to do that.  Your scheme also doesn't scale so well since each slave needs one dedicated line to the master.

Since you're already willing to run two signals plus ground to each slave, CAN seems like a obvious way to go.  CAN scales to a bit over 100 nodes, all connected to the same two data lines plus ground.  The two data lines are actually a differential signal, so have good noise immunity.  That's important when you're going relatively long distances, like 10s of meters.

What makes CAN useful is that the protocol has been carefully thought out to deal with collisions, retries, message validation, and clock drift.  What makes it convenient is that all these things come built into silicon on many small microcontrollers.  The hardware takes care of sending and receiving whole packets, including generating and validating the 16 bit CRC checksum, detecting collision, backoff, retry, and clock sync.

CAN is a peer to peer network.  Any node can send a packet, and all the others can receive it.  Each message has either a 11 or 29 bit ID, and up to 8 data bytes.

You are using PIC 18F4550.  The 18F4580 is pretty much the same thing with a CAN controller added.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want something more convenient. But it would be possible to try out various other arrangements.

Some initial thoughts about difficulties are that your devices will be (1) at varying lengths from each other, and (2) running on completely asynchronous clocks. Your clock line will be received (due to signal delay, micro hardware delay, *and* due to their own software delays) at different moments by the different devices. So you need to make certain that your data set up times are long enough to ensure that it is present and solid by the time each device recognizes the clock edge (assuming you plan to use an edge to trigger data sampling.) You may also need some way to re-synchronize all your devices in case one of them (or more) gets "lost" or improperly starts up thinking it is in the middle of a communication from your master. You may want to have a very clear "start" signal design. (For this, you could look into existing protocols, such as those meant to communicate with serial EEPROMs or I2C.)

One commonly used approach -- I've seen this used in commercial products -- is to tie each of your devices "in series" (TX of one device tied to RX of next, that TX then connected with the RX of the still further next device, etc.) with RS-232 hardware signalling and using the usual asynchronous serial port of the micro. Each device is then responsible for recognizing and passing along any communications not meant for it. There may be delays here, but with your "turn on lights" behavior I don't think this will matter much. Another problem is that they are in serial, so if some wire gets disconnected or shorted then you've got the whole system down.

Another would be for you to look into using open-drain on a shared "party line" (or, as I've used before, two shared open drain party lines -- one for initiating arbitration and one for resolving ownership) used to resolve ownership of the single serial port line pair. In the way I've done it before, I required four wires for any number of devices. The serial port pair was kept in high impedance at all times when not in use (other schemes I can imagine may work here, too.) The other pair was shared by all, but the outputs were operated open-drain with an external pull-up each. One of these was used to initiate an arbitration dialog for ownership (which I called the ***grant*** line) of the serial port pair. Any device could attempt to pull down the arbitration grant line at any time if it reads that the arbitration grant line isn't already pulled down. Any other device, seeing that the arbitration grant line is already pulled down will NOT attempt to engage in arbitration itself but will instead wait to see if the arbitration grant line becomes once again inactive at some time in the future. Until then, all devices waiting to gain ownership simply wait.

Now it is possible that two or three devices may observe the arbitration grant line as not pulled down, decide to pull it down, and then observe that they successfully did pull it down (by looking) and therefore believe that they have won ownership of the serial port. This would be *bad*. So, the second line (which I called the arbitration ***id*** line) is used to serially shift out a binary pattern representing their own personal ID code in binary. The master would be assigned "0000" (or any number of bits you want to assign each device.) Other devices would have other numbers. They serial out each bit onto the arbitration ID line (while all of them keeping the arbitration grant line pulled down, as it isn't yet resolved who owns things), one at a time. They then read back the bit to see if it matches their own. If it doesn't (and that means they tried to serial out an open-drain "1" when someone else tried to apply an open-drain "0"), they released their hold on the arbitration grant line and got off all the party lines. They lost the arbitration and now must wait until the arbitration line is once again released.

In short order, and certainly by the time that all the ID bits are shifted out, someone is the winner. They then hold onto the grant line until they are done with the serial port line. Since they win, they configure their serial port pair (I used bit-banging for this) where they set up the TX as an output and the RX as an input. All other devices reverse that order and listen.

The timing I had to use on each processor had to take into account the relative delays in reaching each device, plus the delays involved in the software observing line conditions and/or setting line conditions. So if you use a polling loop, for example, you need to account for the time required to go completely around the loop in each device and the fact that different processors may be in different places in their own loops and on different clocks. The computation of the time period isn't hard to do. But it is necessary to make sure there is no confusion.

(My situation was a set of devices being tested after being manufactured and before full qualification for shipment. There would be some arbitrary number of devices being set up on a table and tied to a master controller used to run the slaves through a variety of tests for a 24-hour period. And we couldn't consider adding RS-485 signalling ICs to boards that normally didn't have such parts on them, so we just used direct I/O pins. So it wasn't the same thing you are considering.)

The hardware signalling you use would have to be appropriate for such long lines. You may use twisted pair as with cat-5, cat-6, etc, and differential drivers. Or you might use RS-232 style single-ended.

Or just avoid everything I just talked about and consider using RS-485 techniques and protocols associated with it for multidrop communications!